# multiple threading.Timer objects execute at the same time

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to run a function at predefined intervals.

```
def func(value):
    print value

t1 = threading.Timer(1, func, [1])
t2 = threading.Timer(4, func, [2])
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I am expecting **`"1"`** to print after a second and then **`"2"`** after 4 seconds. However, nothing is printed until 4 seconds when they both print.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are you running your code? I'm using ipython on terminal and it works as expected

Comment: Sublime, I'll try another method in the morning as report my results.

Comment: Works as expected from command prompt ubuntu 16.04/py 2.7.12

Comment: Yep, it seems to be working. It must have something to do with sublime

Comment: Actually I was running with python3 in sublime text. Running with python2.7 seems to work now.